# What does ContentPlaceHolderID mean?

Tags: html, asp.net, view, contentplaceholder

In a LogOn view, I have the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

What does this fragment mean and where is "MainContent" defined?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your replies. I now understand how it works, but where is "MainContent" defined? Is it defined in the master page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ContentPlaceHolderID` describes the `ContentPlaceHolder` in the master page where the content will be placed.

Here is the MSDN Documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.contentplaceholderid(v=vs.110).aspx

Say you have multiple content placeholders in your master page. You can tell each of your content controls on your page where to place the content. These `Content` controls do not need to be in the order they appear in your master page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another resource here:[Content Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

That `Content` tag corresponds to a `ContentPlaceHolder` tag in the master page. It would have the id that the `ContentPlaceHolderID` property specifies, so it would look something like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

The content of the `Content` tag will be inserted where `ContentPlaceHolder` tag is in the master page when the page is rendered.